# Multiple background gradients using Compass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

How do you write multiple background gradients using Compass? The docs only show examples of writing a single gradient at a time and I can't find anything about it by googling except a google group discussion that went quiet over two years ago! There must be a way of doing it cos layering up gradients is quite common practice I thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write them like so:

```
div{
  @include background( linear-gradient(top left, #333, rgba(1,1,1, .3)),
                       radial-gradient(#c00, #fff 100px));
}
```

source: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/

(ugly but working) example: http://codepen.io/nobitagit/pen/cFjkv

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when I use FireFox. Safari all good, Chrome good. IE < 9 also not working.

Comment: Quite strange as I see it working on FF, re-tested it right now and looks ok. IE9 and below do not support gradients so you should consider adding a fallback if you need to support those versions of IE. See: http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients for support tables.